# Исключение вещественных чисел в int

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени, 
появилась некоторая необходимость в языке, который я не знаю абсолютно.
Собственно, по заданию необходимо сделать ввод и вывод по каждому типу переменной.
string принимает любой ввод,
double тоже принимает любое число,
А как быть с int? Cделал так, чтобы оно не принимало строку, но при вводе вещественного, программа ломается. Как быть в данной ситуации?
Вот тот кусочек программы..

```
 List<int> mylist(0);
             while (true)
                    {
                     int r;
                     cout<<"Реализация списка для типа Int"<<endl;
                     cout<<"1) Добавить элемент"<<endl;
                    ...................
                     cin>>r;
                     if (r==0) {mylist.~List();break;}
                     switch (r)
                        {
                         case 1:
                            {
                             int st;
                             cout<<"Введите элемент"<<endl;
                             while (!(cin >> st))
                            {
                                cin.clear();
                                while (cin.get() != '\n');
                                cout << "Неверный ввод. Повторите." << endl;
                                cout <<"Введите целое число "<< endl;
                            }
                             mylist.add(st);
                             system("pause");
                             continue;
                            }
                    .......................
                        }
```

Comment: Вообще для полного контроля стоит, наверно, читать всю строку, которую ввели, а дальше уже разбираться, корректна она или нет, разбирать на части и т.д.

Comment: Даже если я и разберу . то что мне с этим делать?Есть ли какая нибудь функция проверки на целочисленность или что нибудь похожее? Например, как в руби `x = 10; x.is_a? Integer #true`

Comment: Проверки на целочисленность ЧЕГО? Строки? Собственно вам и предложили проверить введенную строку на корректность (с помощью регэкспа, например), и потом в зависимости от результата проверки или переводить строку в число с помощью функции `atoi`, или выдавать ошибку.

Comment: Если особо не заморачиваться, то проще читать как вещественное, а потом проверить, целое оно или нет.  Например: `double r; int i; ... cin >> r; i = r; if (i != r) error("Not integer"); ...`

Comment: @avp при таком раскладе записываются нереальные цифры , такие как 19999992391 ~

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) - там сообщается, **где** закончилось целочисленное значение, и если после него остались какие-то цифры или что еще - считайте ввод неверным.

Comment: @QWD666, где-то в другом месте ошибаетесь. Попробуйте `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  double r;
  int i;

  while (cin >> r) {
    i = r;
    if (i != r)
      cout << "not integer, repeat\n";
    else
      cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
  }
}` / У меня работает